# std::pair iterator without default constructor

Tags: c++, stdmap, std-pair

I have an `std::map` mapping to objects which don't have default constructors.
I need an iterator to iterate over the map, but the iterator needs a default constructor, how do I solve this?

```
std::map<MyClass1, MyClass2> MyMap; //No default constructor needed
std::pair<MyClass1, MyClass2> MapIterator; //Need default constructor to construct std::pair
```

Comment: Um, a map iterator is not simply a pair. I think you need `std::map<MyClass1, MyClass2>::iterator` or `std::map<MyClass1, MyClass2>::const_iterator`.

Comment: Why are you explicitly trying to construct an iterator?  You could just use std::map<MyClass1, MyClass2>::iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think a `pair` is a map iterator? In your case a `std::map<MyClass1, MyClass2>::iterator` is a map iterator. And it is default constructible.